# how remove import library google-play-services_lib in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, google-cloud-messaging

I'm implementing Push notifications in my android app.I need google-play-services_lib for GCM support. But

> Accidentally I choose
>   extras->google->google_play_services->libproject->
>   google-play-services_lib while importing library

with this all my errors are gone and is working. Later I noticed Google doc says

> you need to copy and import that source, NOT the source in SDK

I tried to remove it and and import copied source, but its not taking as same library name is already stored somewhere! How can I point to new library path ? and remove SDK path lib ?

Thanks

Comment: Moved to Android studio

Comment: tried that, but some reason I faced problem in the beginning so can't go ahead

Comment: Please do some searching before asking

Comment: rightclick on googleplayservices sdk and select delete. Dialog will open from that check remove project content on disk. download service library from sdk manager and now you can import it freely.

Comment: @KaranMer I guess this should do the trick, as it search for the location and found it missing. I'll try this and let you know

Comment: @Ashok while importing **do not forget to check copy project into workspace**

Answer (score 1):

You can do this way for Eclipse:

Steps for **remove library** project:

1. **Right click** on **project**
2. Go to **property**
3. Click on **Android** (2nd tab)
4. Click on **Google Play Service Library**
5. Click on **Remove**
6. Click **Apply**
7. Click **OK**

Screenshot for your reference:[image: this one]

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this and it did removed it, But When I tried to import with new source location its not taking (I'm not able to import), may be because it stored library information somwhere!? I want this library to be removed from the list (in add button and project) so that I can point to new location.

Comment: @Ashok, Go to /...your path to sdk sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms

Comment: @Ashok, if you have solved your problem so can you please accept answer ?

Comment: I don't understand what to do with this path sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms ?

Comment: @Ashok, Right click in workspace -> Import -> Android - Select project from existing workspace -> select above path - > ok